# Write and read 3D arrays in R

Tags: arrays, r, file, data-structures

I have a 3D array in R constructed as (although the names don’t seem to show up):

```
v.arr <- array(1:18, c(2,3,3), dimnames = c("A", "B", "X",
                          "Y","Z","P","Q","R"))
```

and it shows up like this when printed to the screen:

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    7    9   11
[2,]    8   10   12

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   13   15   17
[2,]   14   16   18
```

I write it out to a file using:

```
write.table(v.arr, file = “Test Data”)
```

I then read it back in with:

```
test.data <- read.table(“Test Data”)
```

and I get this:

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9
1  1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17
2  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18
```

Obviously, I need to do something to either structure the file before writing or restructure it on the read-back to get back the 3D array. I can always restructure the data that I get from reading. Is that the best approach? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to use this data in R or also read it with other software? If only with R, why not just use .rda (RData) format with `save` (and `load`) commands..?

Comment: What's the purpose of the dimnames argument in the array construction? It appears to be ignored. I think it needed to be a list with three entries for it to have any effect...

Comment: dimnames will assign names to the dimensions of the array, but I needed to add ‘list’ to the name vector. It will be ignored if an error occurs.Yes, answer below suggesting that I use the RData format is a good solution. If I need to export the data I’ll cross the bridge when I come to it. Thanks, everyone for comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue is that you are using `write.table` to do this, so it is (I believe) coercing your array to a table. If you are looking to save it and don't mind that it would be in an R-specific format, you can easily use the `save` and `load` functions.

```
save(v.arr,file = "~/Desktop/v.arr.RData")
rm(list=ls())

load("~/Desktop/v.arr.RData")
v.arr
```

Comment: Yes, this is internal intermediate data and this is a perfect solution. Don’t anticipate a need to export it at the moment. Thanks!!

Comment: The correct use of dimnames in this care should have been: dimnames = list(c("A", “B"), c("X","Y",”Z”),c("P","Q","R”)))

Comment: Probably meant to put that up on the question?

Comment: Actually, not. Main objective was the write-read issue. I am using a test case here and I have already worked this out for the actual dimnames for the actual 3D array. But, in case others are reading I thought I should add this comment.

Comment: Worth pointing out that `save`/`load` has other advantages as well: the file will be much smaller, and (if the array is at all large) the loading will be much faster.